# Memory Leak using Windows ThreadPool API

Tags: threadpool

I am using Windows ThreadPools in my application, and am experiencing a memory leak of 136 bytes for every call to CreateThreadPoolWork(), as seen via UMDH:

```
+ 1257728 ( 1286424 -  28696)   9459 allocs BackTraceB0035CC
+    9248 (   9459 -    211)    BackTraceB0035CC    allocations

    ntdll!RtlUlonglongByteSwap+B52
    ntdll!TpAllocWork+8D
    KERNEL32!CreateThreadpoolWork+25
    ... My Code ...
```

I am using Cleanup Group, so per the documentation I am not calling CloseThreadPoolWork().

My code for handling the ThreadPool is:

```
typedef PTP_WORK ThreadHandle_t;
typedef PTP_WORK_CALLBACK THREAD_ENTRY_POINT_T;

static PTP_POOL pool = NULL;
static TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON CallBackEnviron;
static PTP_CLEANUP_GROUP cleanupgroup = NULL;

int mtInitialize()
{
    InitializeThreadpoolEnvironment(&CallBackEnviron);

    pool = CreateThreadpool(NULL);

    if (NULL == pool)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    cleanupgroup = CreateThreadpoolCleanupGroup();

    if (NULL == cleanupgroup)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    SetThreadpoolCallbackPool(&CallBackEnviron, pool);

    SetThreadpoolCallbackCleanupGroup(&CallBackEnviron, cleanupgroup, NULL);

    return 0; // Success
}

void mtDestroy()
{
    CloseThreadpoolCleanupGroupMembers(cleanupgroup, FALSE, NULL);
    CloseThreadpoolCleanupGroup(cleanupgroup);
    DestroyThreadpoolEnvironment(&CallBackEnviron);
    CloseThreadpool(pool);
}

//Create thread
ThreadHandle_t mtRunThread(THREAD_ENTRY_POINT_T entry_point, void *thread_args)
{
    PTP_WORK work = NULL;

    work = CreateThreadpoolWork(entry_point, thread_args, &CallBackEnviron);

    if (NULL == work) {
        // CreateThreadpoolWork() failed.
        return 0;
    }

    SubmitThreadpoolWork(work);

    return work;
}

//Wait for a thread to finish
void mtWaitForThread(ThreadHandle_t thread)
{
    WaitForThreadpoolWorkCallbacks(thread, FALSE);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Any ideas why I'm leaking memory?

Comment: Reading an article on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456398.aspx), I saw a comment: "If you fail to call CloseThreadpoolCleanupGroupMembers, your application will leak memory."
In my code, I only call this function at the end of the application. So, this would explain a memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you figured it out, given your comment, but the problem is that you only call `CloseThreadpoolCleanupGroupMembers()` in `mtDestroy()`.

If you have a persistent thread pool the memory will not be freed unless you call `CloseThreadpoolCleanupGroupMembers()` periodically.  Your code and comments suggests that you do, though I can't confirm this without the code responsible for creating and destroying your thread pool.

My recommendation for persistent thread pools is to just call `CloseThreadpoolWork()` in the callback functions.  Microsoft's recommendations work better if you're creating and destroying thread pools, but `CloseThreadpoolWork()` is simpler and easier than periodically calling `CloseThreadpoolCleanupGroupMembers()` if you're maintaining one thread pool for the life of your application.

By the way, it's safe to do both as long as you tell `CloseThreadpoolCleanupGroupMembers()` to cancel any pending callbacks (pass `fCancelPendingCallbacks` as `TRUE`) to ensure `CloseThreadpoolWork()` is called on any cleaned up work items:

> You can revoke the work object’s membership only by closing it, which
>   can be done on an individual basis with the CloseThreadpoolWork
>   function. The thread pool knows that the work object is a member of
>   the cleanup group and revokes its membership before closing it. This
>   ensures that the application doesn’t crash when the cleanup group
>   later attempts to close all of its members. The inverse isn’t true: If
>   you first instruct the cleanup group to close all of its members and
>   then call CloseThreadpoolWork on the now invalid work object, your
>   application will crash.

From [Windows with C++ - Thread Pool Cancellation and Cleanup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456398.aspx)